# create new df by adding the values of two columns

Tags: python

I am creating a new data series from another, I am using the following code

```
df = lcldf.groupby('DateTime', as_index=False)[(lcldf['Response KWH/hh (per half hour) ']) & (lcldf['KWH/hh (per half hour) '])].sum()
```

I want to add the values of the columns `(lcldf['Response KWH/hh (per half hour)` and `(lcldf['KWH/hh (per half hour)`  for the same dates `lcldf['Date']`, however, I got the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

I do not know if I can perform this operation at the same time, if it is not possible why could be the way to do it?

The original df is:

```
House     DateTime                    KWH/hh (per half hour)    Response KWH/hh (per half hour)  
1         11/8/2012  10:30:00 AM      2                         1
1         11/8/2012  11:00:00 AM      5                         4
1         11/8/2012  11:30:00 AM      1                         1
2         11/8/2012  10:30:00 AM      2                         1
2         11/8/2012  11:00:00 AM      5                         4
2         11/8/2012  11:30:00 AM      1                         1
3         11/8/2012  10:30:00 AM      2                         1
3         11/8/2012  11:00:00 AM      5                         4 
3         11/8/2012  11:30:00 AM      1                         1
```

And the expected output would be something like this (dflcl)

```
DateTime                    KWH/hh (per half hour)    Response KWH/hh (per half hour)  
11/8/2012  10:30:00 AM      6                         3
11/8/2012  11:00:00 AM      15                        12
11/8/2012  11:30:00 AM      3                         3
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your df and expected output?

Comment: I edited the question with a sample of the output, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = lcldf.groupby('DateTime').sum()[["KWH/hh (per half hour)", "Response KWH/hh (per half hour)"]]
```